# Why sometimes illustrator rasterize text?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, rasterization

**I explain with this simple experiment below :**
1) I create a complex shape with a text
2) I duplicate-it 8 time
3) I select all, I copy-it and I paste-it
4) I press cmd-Y to see the GPU Preview and I see that the last text can't be edited anymore. It's rasterized, It's not a text it's a photo :(

Does anyone know why?

[image]

Comment: I have never seen this behaviour before. It'd be difficult to answer your question without looking at your files / software / hardware, so I'm voting it as off-topic